# TF Object Detection API Mixed Precision

Tags: tensorflow, precision, object-detection-api, mixed

I'm using the TensorFlow Object Detection API for training a detection model on a V100 GPU. Since it has tensor cores available, is there any config flag / kwarg available to turn on mixed precision training? Not sure if this is a current feature or not. Something similar to `model_main.py --mixed` would be awesome if it exists.

Answer (score 0):

Yesterday (May 16th) Nvidia showcased Automatic Mixed Precision, which greatly eases the implementation of this feature, lowering the effort massively: add one line of code and voilá!!!.

It seems the webcast was recorded and will be available on demand, here the links meanwhile:

https://developer.nvidia.com/automatic-mixed-precision

https://devblogs.nvidia.com/nvidia-automatic-mixed-precision-tensorflow/

Also talks about strategies, tools and things to avoid when implementing MP/AMP.

There is an excellent paper that talks about an implementation (among other things) of Mixed Precision. I've prepared this 4-min video that summarizes the research "Supercharging AI with high performance distributed computing"

http://youtu.be/JvssZESVcjI)

BTW, according to Nvidia MP can be effectively implemented on Volta and Turing GPUs (i.e. Google Collab uses Voltas V100!) and AMP (Automatic Mixed Precision is integrated on TF1.14)